# Conditional formating in VBA, same color, multiple strings?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I have this code for conditionnal formating, where i'm only changing the string:

```
Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

With Range("$A$1:$H$17").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlTextString, String:="CPA", TextOperator:=xlContains)
    .Interior.Color = RGB(105, 191, 44)
End With
With Range("$A$1:$H$17").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlTextString, String:="CPN", TextOperator:=xlContains)
    .Interior.Color = RGB(105, 191, 44)
End With
With Range("$A$1:$H$17").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlTextString, String:="CSS", TextOperator:=xlContains)
    .Interior.Color = RGB(105, 191, 44)
End With
With Range("$A$1:$H$17").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlTextString, String:="RL", TextOperator:=xlContains)
    .Interior.Color = RGB(105, 191, 44)
End With
```

Is there any alternative for all these lines, so i can write it in a shorter and more effective way?

This macro colors even the cells wich contains "CPAzergfzergfer". how can i write a macro where i only color cells containing the exact string ?

Comment: Please mention the programming language you're using and add an appropriate tag

Comment: Just updated it, thanks Ohad Eytan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array to specify the conditions for the conditional formatting, like this:

```
myArray = Array("CPA", "CPN", "CSS", "RL")
For myLoop = LBound(myArray) to UBound(myArray)
    With Range("$A$1:$H$17").FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlTextString, String:=myArray(myLoop), TextOperator:=xlEqual)
        .Interior.Color = RGB(105, 191, 44)
    End With
Next
```

I've also changed the `TextOperator` so it should only select items that match the text value, rather than select items which **contain** the text value.

Answer (score 0):

Dave's answer is great. Here's another option. This puts all the conditions in one formula, which I think makes it easier to manage in the not-so-great conditional formatting dialog box.

I turned on the macro recorder and opened the CF dialog and entered this formula:

```
=OR(A1="CPA",A1="CPN",A1="CSS",A1="RL")
```

Here's the cleaned-up version of thecode that was generated:

```
Sub Macro1()
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H17").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(A1=""CPA"",A1=""CPN"",A1=""CSS"",A1=""RL"")"
Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(105, 191, 44)
End Sub
```